# Best approach to handle common application configuration in multiple environments using Spring Cloud Config

Tags: git, spring-boot, configuration, puppet, spring-cloud-config

Before using Spring Cloud Config, my team was using Puppet for application configuration in multiple different environments (dev, test, preprod, prod). Our scenarios are the typical ones: common properties between applications plus specific ones combined between all environments.

In order to cope with all the possible different values of the same configuration property based on the environment, together with those configuration properties shared by several applications in the same environment, we came up with the approach of defining a "common" configuration file per environment with all the possible "replacement" values (which we coined as "tokens").

So for example, let's put that we have 5 applications in the "dev" environment that share 2 database URLs. We would create the following "common" configuration file with the following "tokens":

```
databaseX.url = jdbc:url:.......
databaseY.url = jdbc:url:.......
```

Then, for each application, we would define its own configuration properties file where we would define placeholders to be replaced by the matching tokens in the "common" configuration file. So for example, this would be the configuration properties file for App1:

```
app.name = App1
property1 = value1
property2 = value2
...
database.url = ${databaseX.url}
```

And this one for App2:

```
app.name = App2
property3 = value3
property4 = value4
...
database.url = ${databaseY.url}
```

See the point? With this approach we could maintain a global "common" configuration properties file per environment where each individual application could decide which property to pick up, and Puppet would simply replace it by the specific "token". **Note that Puppet would only replace the requested "tokens", not the full "common" configuration properties file.**

However, when moving to Spring Cloud Config, I have not yet figured out how to implement this approach, as having a "common" configuration properties file (the top level `application.yaml` in terms of Spring Cloud Config's hierarchy) always results in **all the properties** defined in such `application.yaml` being copied to the all the applications, hence each individual application ending up with lots of properties that it doesn't require (and posing a security/privacy issue as well, of course).

Therefore, is there a mechanism in Spring Cloud Config by which I can simply **replace parent's properties if and only if its counterpart placeholder is defined** in the application configuration, and consequently discarding the rest of properties not explicitly requested as placeholders?

The approach would be similar to what the Resources Filter plugin does for Maven:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

I'd love to hear from people having solved this issue through Spring Cloud Config.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the use of `profiles` allowed us to get the expected behaviour.